# How to add iOS text notification actions

Tags: iphone, ipad, swift, notifications, ios8

I am creating an app for iOS and right now i'm working with the notification part. I wanted to use some of the new notification features in my app, action. Something I can't find in Apple's WWDC 2014 is how to use text notification action like in the Message app.The only thing I could find was regular buttons. If you know how to program this in swift, please help me!!!